# Problems with duplicate photos on Photos app

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, photos.app

I've been trying to shrink my Photos Library with no luck. I have some duplicate photos, inherited from the iPhoto days, as the result of syncing my iPhone photos via iCloud and making a local copy of those same photos "just in case" on an iPhoto album. Now, I'm facing the task of deleting one of those duplicates using PhotoSweeper X, which is pretty handy, but I can't see where those duplicates come from. For instance:

[image: PhotoSweeperX preview]

One of those photos is actually on an album called "iPhone security copy", but I can't see the real path on the app. Is there any app that can detect duplicates, and also show the real album for those photos?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PhotoSweeper shows library-based paths in the path control. You need to change Preferences to show file-based paths (the menu PhotoSweeper > Preferences; the General page, Path Bar: Show file path).

Answer (score -2):

Default Image Capture app is very simple and predictable. You can import and duplicate photos with it without any side effects.

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved if you described how to use "Default Image Capture" to detect duplicate images and show the real album the duplicate photos come from.